# Failed to annotate a left join query in django 1.8

Tags: sql, django

I try to a new field praise_cnt to 'Store' in django 1.8 but failed. Here is my code.

I've two models:

```
class Store(models.Model):
    ...

class Works(models.Model):
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store)
    ...
```

The query is :

```
sql = 'select store.*, sum(works.praise_cnt) as praise_cnt from store left join works on store.id = works.store_id ' \
                  'where store.is_active=1 and store.audit_status=1 ' \
                  'group by store.id order by praise_cnt desc limit %d,%d' %(offset, rows)

store_list = Store.objects.raw(sql)

for store in store_list:
    print store.praise_cnt
```

The sql is right but the value of store is always 'None'. So how to add a praise_cnt field to store in this case? Thanks

**UPDATE： I solve this issue by myself. I replaced 'sum(works.praise_cnt) as praise_cnt' with 'sum(works.praise_cnt) as cnt' and it works. I seems that django doesn't support annotate a new field with same name.**

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using raw SQL instead of Django's ORM? It would be much easier to achieve this using the ORM.

Comment: @solarissmoke the efficiency of orm is too low in this case

Comment: looks ok. Check for twice sql (print it and copy-paste to db). Offtopic: move parameters to raw method like [example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/sql/#adding-annotations) `...ts.raw(sql, [ offset, rows ] )`

Comment: @danihp I double checked the sql, it looks ok in sql client

Comment: Just for test, in order to isolate issue: can you replace count for a hardcoded value? Also, without group by either joins.